# Code to Show for One post only in head

Tags: headers, code

I want to add this code only for one post before `</head>`

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="http://abc.com"/>
```

What code shall i use?

Answer (score 0):

Write a function, and define it as a callback on the `wp_head` hook:

```
<?php
/**
 * print a alternate link on head for a several post
 *
 * @wp-hook wp_head
 * @return void
 */
function wpse_162849_print_alternate_link() {

    //don't do anything expect on singular pages
    if ( ! is_singular() )
        return;

    // check the global post
    if ( empty( $GLOBALS[ 'post' ] )
        return;

    // compare the post-ID
    $your_post_ID = 42;
    if ( $your_post_ID != $GLOBALS[ 'post' ]->ID )
        return;

    echo '<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="http://abc.com"/>';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_162849_print_alternate_link' );
```

Change the post ID to your needs. You can also implement another logic to choose the right post, for example by a special post meta.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) which can be used to determine various things, e.g. if we are on the right post. The [`wp_head`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) action hook can be used to add things to the `head` section. For below exemplary post is use the conditional tag [`is_single()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single), which can be used for any post type, but `attachment` and `page`, it takes one parameter, which is `$post` and can be the ID, title or slug.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse162894_add_alternate_lang_href_to_post' );
function wpse162894_add_alternate_lang_href_to_post() {
    if ( is_single( 'your-posts-slug' ) ) {
        $link_rel = '<link rel="%s" hreflang="%s" href="%s" />';
        $rel      = 'alternate';
        $hreflang = 'en-gb';
        $href     = 'http://an-url.org';
        printf( $link_rel, $rel, $hreflang, $href );
    }   
}
```